# Select or drop rows by group threshold

Tags: python, pandas

Having a dataframe like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'Beverage': ['Beer', 'Wine', 'Whisky'],
            'G1_1': [11, 5.1, 2.8],
            'G1_2': [6, 4, 0],
            'G1_3': [0, 2, 0],
            'G2_1': [0, 4.1, 0.8],
            'G2_2': [0, 6, 0.1],
            'G2_3': [0, 9.4, 0],
            }
                )

group1 = ['G1_1', 'G1_2', 'G1_3']

df

  Beverage  G1_1    G1_2    G1_3    G2_1    G2_2    G2_3
0   Beer    11.0    6       0       0       0       0
1   Wine    5.1     4       2       4.1     6.0     9.4
2   Whisky  2.8     0       0       0.8     0.1     0.0
```

if we want to select all rows for which `group1` samples have at least 2 non-zero values, one possible solution is to convert zero values to `NaN` and then use pandas `DF.dropna` for the filtering. For example:

```
df.replace({0: np.nan}).dropna(axis=0, thresh=2, subset=group1)
df

  Beverage  G1_1    G1_2    G1_3    G2_1    G2_2    G2_3
0   Beer    11.0    6       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   Wine    5.1     4       2       4.1     6.0     9.4
```

the above dropped the `Whisky` row because there were less than two samples in `group1` with non-zero values.

How would it be possible to apply a similar filter, but instead of filtering for zeros, apply some particular condition, for example, that at least 2 samples in `group1` have values `>5`? (in this case only the `Beer` line should be printed)

Edit:

also, are there more efficient ways to accomplish the same? I'm asking this because I'll have to apply the filter to a really big dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `DataFrame` comparison operators (eq, ne, le, lt, ge, gt), and then `sum` the Boolean values along the rows to form a mask.

```
# At least 2 non-zero values
thresh = 2
m = df[group1].ne(0).sum(1).ge(thresh)
df.loc[m]
#  Beverage  G1_1  G1_2  G1_3  G2_1  G2_2  G2_3
#0     Beer  11.0     6     0   0.0   0.0   0.0
#1     Wine   5.1     4     2   4.1   6.0   9.4

# At least 2 values greater than 5
thresh = 2
m = df[group1].gt(5).sum(1).ge(thresh)
df.loc[m]
#  Beverage  G1_1  G1_2  G1_3  G2_1  G2_2  G2_3
#0     Beer  11.0     6     0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

---

More complex selections can be created by combining these with `&` or `|`. For instance, values within the interval (2, 4]:

```
df[group1].gt(2) & df[group1].le(4)
```

Comment: In my rough tests, this approach was slightly faster than the others.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the following logic:

```
 inds = (df[group_1] > 5).sum(axis=1) >= 2
 df.loc[inds, :]
```

In words, this translates to:

1. Check for a condition (e.g. `> 5`) for all values, then
2. Check how often per row this condition is satisfied (`.sum(axis=1)`) and then
3. Specifying the number of times this condition must be satisfied to retain the row (`>= 2`)

I like this approach because it is versatile and can easily be translated to different problems

Answer (score 0):

Figured that one possible solution is to generate a suitable mapping dictionary for `df.replace`. For example:

```
rep_d = {k: np.nan for k in range(0, 5)}
df.replace(rep_d).dropna(axis=0, thresh=2, subset=group1)
df

  Beverage  G1_1    G1_2    G1_3    G2_1    G2_2    G2_3
0   Beer    11.0    6       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

But not sure how efficient this solution is for a very large dataframe.